# How to config Router in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const { connectToMongoDB } = require("./connect");
const urlRoute = require("./routes/url");
const URL = require("./models/url");

const app = express();
const PORT = 8001;

connectToMongoDB("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/short-url").then(() =>
  console.log("Mongodb connected")
);

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/url", urlRoute);

app.get("/:shortId", async (req, res) => {
  const shortId = req.params.shortId;
  const entry = await URL.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      shortId,
    },
    {
      $push: {
        visitHistory: {
          timestamp: Date.now(),
        },
      },
    }
  ); 
  try {
    res.redirect(entry.redirectURL, res.redirect);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Started at PORT:${PORT}`));
```

routes/url.js

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  handleGenerateNewShortURL,
  handleGetAnalytics,
} = require("../controllers/url");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", handleGenerateNewShortURL);

router.get("/analytics/:shortId", handleGetAnalytics);

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/url.js

```
const shortid = require("shortid");
const URL = require("../models/url");

async function handleGenerateNewShortURL(req, res) {
  const body = req.body;
  console.log(body);
  if (!body.url) return res.status(400).json({ error: "url is required" });
  const shortID = shortid();

  await URL.create({
    shortId: shortID,
    redirectURL: body.url,
    visitHistory: [],
  });

  return res.json({ id: shortID });
}

async function handleGetAnalytics(req, res) {
  const shortId = req.params.shortId;
  const result = await URL.findOne({ shortId });
  return res.json({
    totalClicks: result.visitHistory.length,
    analytics: result.visitHistory,
  });
}

module.exports = {
  handleGenerateNewShortURL,
  handleGetAnalytics,
};
```

app.use("/url", urlRoute);
is not routing request.
What I am missing or what need to modify?

app.use("/url", urlRoute); not working
expecting It should work.

when directly used app.use("/url", handleGenerateNewShortURL) after exporting from routes/url.js it is working fine but when write as mentioned In code block it is not working.

Comment: Which URL are you hitting when you said that things are not working `/url` or `/url/`? Because your routing seems to be configured for the second scenario.

Comment: Make sure you are using POST while sending data to HOST/url